# Is PostgreSQL database optimised for any particular CPU?

Tags: performance, hardware, postgresql, central-processing-unit

This question may sound strange, but some CPU have instruction sets for virtualisation technologies, while some non-related software can use those sets, or even GPU to improve their performance.
So, anything like this for PostgreSQL, or is it something along the lines of *"install 4x 8core of latest stuff and be happy"*?

Comment: I don't think this is worthy of an answer, but I suppose you could say that the database might benefit from running on the amd64 architecture depending on your data set and whether or not 64-bit allows PostgreSQL to work more efficiently. Also, Ignacio is right, the amount of memory installed and hard drive speed is going to matter a lot more than CPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Databases don't actually use the CPU very much. I/O is far more important for database performance.